# Run time Error 1004 - copy selected sheet failure

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I'm trying to fix this error for a coworker, but extremely rusty on the code work.

```
Sub SelectPricingSheet() 
'Copy userform1 selected Pricing sheet after Import Sheet.

    CreateSheetList                    ' Subroutine: Build list of Price sheets
    Load UserForm1                     ' Load form to select price sheet
    UserForm1.Show                     ' Show form to select price sheet

    If SelectedSheet <> "" Then        ' Test no selected sheet
        Sheets(SelectedSheet).Copy After:=Sheets("Import") 'Copy selected sheet after Import Sheet
    Else
    End If                              ' No processing
End Sub
```

Errors out at this line.

```
Sheets(SelectedSheet).Copy After:=Sheets("Import")          ' Copy selected sheet after the Import Sheet
```

Comment: What is the value of `SelectedSheet` when the error occurs? Does a sheet with that name actually exist?

Comment: SelectedSheet  actually ties directly to one of 3 sheets...EA, LF, or SF.  when running the macro, pop up box comes up stating to select one of the 3 sheets. once selected, then run-time error happens

Comment: I don't see where your userform value `SelectedSheet` is getting passed back into the sub.

Comment: just before the line that causes the error, add a temporary line: `MsgBox SelectedSheet` .  this will pop up a message box with the value of `selectedsheet`... is the value what you expect?

Comment: No message box popped up, but it actually works

Comment: Recommended: [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) . . if you can't get it figured out, can you add the code that assigns SelectedSheet it's value?

Comment: @HeatherLongardner -  **No** message box??  Then that section of code isn't running at all. Even if it's "working" now, I'd suggest you use [F8] to step through the code line-by-line to try to figure out how it works  (instructions in the link above)